# Angular ngRepeat object deep, performance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have complicated json object (more then 100 items) and I need to run with `ngRepeat` directive over some values and show only one value.

**Complicated object**

```
$scope.complicatedList = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": [
      {
        "data": {
          "otherdata": "sss"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  ....
];
```

On other hand I thought to create new object generated from complicated one and play with new created (with underscore for example)

**Short version of complicated object**

```
  $scope.shortVersionList = [
      {id: 1, "otherdata": "sss1"},
      {id: 2, "otherdata": "sss2"},
      {id: 3, "otherdata": "sss3"},
      ...
      {id: 100, "otherdata": "sss3"}
    ];
```

I try to understand before to go to implement: is there any performance difference should be?

I use angular that runs on iOS/Android (Cordova+Ionic) and I don't know if its good way to store in service two versions of Object (actual and short version) or store only one object and play with HTML only.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have a separate service/method that returns the short object, instead of filtering it in the html rendering phase, as it would slow down rendering. While for normal browsers on standard hardware the difference would be negligible, in your case, with ios/android devices, I recommend using the separate object.

Edit:

Note, however, that performance wise there wouldn't be any measurable difference between:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="complicatedItem in complicatedList">
  {{complicatedItem.nested.moreNested.evenMoreNested.someValue}}
</div>
```

vs

```
<div data-ng-repeat="simpleItem in simpleItemList">
   {{simpleItem.someValue}}
</div>
```

What I was trying to advise you is not to have logic in the ng-repeats and/or add additional ng-repeats. If that is not the case and data can be presented without adding additional ng-repeats, then both the first and the second variant that I showed you will have the same performance. The second is slightly better in readability but it comes in the cost of having to maintain two service methods.